# Ignore "Certificate Verification" for self-signed certificate in C++

Tags: c++, apache, ssl, cgi, xml-rpc

I am running a CGI script in C++ using xml-rpc library. The server code is located in /var/www/cgi-bin/ directory to be run by Apache. Apache is also configured to allow permission running the cgi. Now the problem is that since Apache on my system has a self-signed certificate, when I run the client to access this address:
"https://localhost/cgi-bin/xmlrpcserver"

It gives me this error: 
Client threw error: Unable to transport XML to server and get XML response back.  libcurl failed to execute the HTTP POST transaction, explaining:  SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

For the time being, how can I bypass checking certificate verification to run and test my application. I want SSL connection (to encrypt the entire communication) while I want to ignore certificate verification and use the current self-sign certificate.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Complex Client pattern in xmlrpc_c library and set no_ssl_verifyhost and no_ssl_verifypeer options in curl transport true:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <xmlrpc-c/client.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::string const serverUrl("https://localhost/cgi-bin/xmlrpcserver");
  std::string const methodName("sample.add");

  xmlrpc_c::clientXmlTransport_curl myTransport
    (xmlrpc_c::clientXmlTransport_curl::constrOpt()
     .no_ssl_verifyhost(true)
     .no_ssl_verifypeer(true)
     );
  xmlrpc_c::client_xml myClient(&myTransport);

  xmlrpc_c::paramList sampleAddParms;
  sampleAddParms.add(xmlrpc_c::value_int(5));
  sampleAddParms.add(xmlrpc_c::value_int(7));

  xmlrpc_c::rpcPtr myRpcP(methodName, sampleAddParms);

  xmlrpc_c::carriageParm_curl0 myCarriageParm(serverUrl);
  myRpcP->call(&myClient, &myCarriageParm);

  int const sum((xmlrpc_c::value_int(myRpcP->getResult())));
  std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think now something is changed. It prints the content of the web page while it still gives me the same error. Shall I use 'curl' handle somewhere in my code? Or it is just global to the entire application?

Comment: I understand the problem. I thought that you are directly using libcurl, but it is not true. xmlrpc_c library performs HTTP request to the server by itself. Please delete my advice from your code. Instead, use Complex Client http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/doc/libxmlrpc_client++.html#complex_client and use xmlrpc_c::clientXmlTransport_curl with xmlrpc_c::clientXmlTransport_curl::constrOpt().no_ssl_verifyhost(true). See http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/doc/libxmlrpc_client++.html#class_curl

Comment: The code is like this: 
string const serverUrl("https://localhost/cgi-bin/xmlrpcserver");
        string const methodName("sample.add");

        xmlrpc_c::clientSimple myClient;
        xmlrpc_c::value result;


        myClient.call(serverUrl, methodName, "ii", &result, 5, 7);

        int const sum = xmlrpc_c::value_int(result);

        cout << "Result of RPC (sum of 5 and 7): " << sum << endl;

Comment: I updated the answer. The trick is use Complex Client pattern in xmlrpc-c and no_ssl_verifyhost option.

Comment: Well, thanks for the consideration and the responses. Shall I do sth for the server side since I have still the same problem. My Server side code is like this: 

        xmlrpc_c::registry myRegistry;

        xmlrpc_c::methodPtr const sampleAddMethodP(new sampleAddMethod);

        myRegistry.addMethod("sample.add", sampleAddMethodP);

        xmlrpc_c::serverCgi myServer(
                xmlrpc_c::serverCgi::constrOpt()
                .registryP(&myRegistry));

        myServer.processCall();

Comment: Added .no_ssl_verifypeer(true) to the above code. I think it should fix the certificate error.

Comment: No actually. It's weird. It still gives me the same error: 

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'girerr::error'
  what():  Unable to transport XML to server and get XML response back.  libcurl failed to execute the HTTP POST transaction, explaining:  SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed